# preserve re.sub captures

Tags: python, regex

I'm using re.sub like this:

```
def some_func(text):
    text = my_regex.sub(lambda m: do_something(m), text)
    return text
```

Sometimes I want to preserve, separately, the things that `my_regex` is capturing.

To do that in one pass, I can imagine `do_something` could alter a `global` variable before returning the text to sub in:

```
captures = []
def do_something(m):
    global captures
    captures = []
    if m.group(1):
         captures.append(m.group(1))
    return 'TEXT_TO_SUB_IN'
```

so that then:

```
def some_func(text):
    text = my_regex.sub(lambda m: do_something(m), text)
    c = deepcopy(captures)
```

But this is terrible. Turning this all into a `class` and doing something similar also seems bad.

Is there better pattern for doing that: for subbing and also returning the captures in one pass?

Comment: Give us an example of how your regex would look if you were going to capture and replace in the same pass.  I know sub doesn't do this, but if we saw how you are thinking of the problem, it could help.

Comment: You could return a tuple of values, the text with the substitution and the match group.

Comment: You don't need to "declare" `captures` as `global` in your example, because you only `.append()` to it. global or nonlocal would be needed if you were to assign to that variable.

Comment: @qarma I am assigning. I'm clearing it with each use.

Comment: Ah, correct; you can also clear a list by `captured[:] = []` without assigning the label `captured` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `global` you can use a closure:

```
def do_whatever():
    def sub(text):
        captured.append(text)
        return "new"

    captured = []
    result = re.sub(r".*", sub, "test test")
    print captured

    captured = []
    result = re.sub(r".*", sub, "foo bar")
    print captured
```

Comment: Really beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the two lines

```
text = my_regex.sub(lambda m: do_something(m), text)
```

and

```
text = my_regex.sub(do_something, text)
```

have identical effect, so there's no need to introduce the complexity of a lambda.

Secondly, in the code

```
global captures
captures = []
if m.group(1):
     captures.append(m.group(1))
```

you should delete the first two statements. You shouldn't set it to empty each time you perform a match or you'll lose the results of previous matches, and since that means you are only *mutating* the list rather than *assigning* to it, you don't need the `global` statement.

But full marks for thinking of a function, which does appear to be the most productive approach.

The value returned by the function given as a first argument to `re.sub` is used as the replacement string, so you don't have the chance to return other values that could be stashed by additional code.

In short, once you remove the deficiencies mentioned above, which I presume are down to simple inexperience, you've actually got a practical solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you - did not realize that re: `lambda` vs just passing in the function. (I did in fact want to clear that global each time, as `some_func` was picking up the result for each pass.)